# Maven and java build path

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, buildpath

I got recently a new laptop at work, and had to install everything new. Eclipse, Maven, SourceTree and import our git-project etc.

But I got many problems to start working..

Here are screenshots of few problems. I think it has something to do with Maven or the Java Build Path.

Java Problems:
"The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved"

Maven Dependency Problem:
"failed to read artifact descriptor for ...." (many libraries)
"Missing artifact ....." (many libraries)

Maven Problem:
"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failure to transfer com.keyboardsamurais.maven:maven-timestamp-plugin:pom:1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.keyboardsamurais.maven:maven-timestamp-plugin:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/185.31.17.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect   pom.xml /reis   line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem"

Has anyone an idea, what could fix that?[image: JAVA EROORS]
[image: MAVEN ERRORS] [image: MAVEN ERRORS2]

Comment: Please post full error messages instead of screenshots. Also, I can't get the point of screenshot 1. What does it show? Where? If you have no other choice than screenshots, please highlight something

Comment: Do you need a Proxy to access the Internet?

Comment: is there a customized settings.xml for maven in you company? Things look quite good but maven needs to be able to resolve and download the dependencies.

Comment: `I got recently a new laptop at work` ask your work for support ? how are the others doing, you should check with your colleagues first, it will be more efficient

Comment: @Thomas yes I need a proxy to access internet

Comment: edited the question. I didn't copy the errors because they are too many, but actually the same errors many times, each one with a different library

Answer (score 1):

Maven does neither use the system's proxy settings nor Eclipse's proxy settings but maintains its own settings in [`settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies):

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  ...
</settings>
```

This file should be in `$MAVEN_HOME$\conf\`